# multiline output in python and using format() in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

can please suggest correct way to represent this print() in python 3.6

```
import run
p1={'name':'Virat Kohli', 'role':'bat', 'runs':112, '4':10, '6':0, 'balls':119, 'field':0} 
p2={'name':'du Plessis', 'role':'bat', 'runs':120, '4':11, '6':2, 'balls':112, 'field':0} 
p3={'name':'Bhuvneshwar Kumar', 'role':'bowl', 'wkts':1, 'overs':10, 'runs':71, 'field':1} 
p4={'name':'Yuzvendra Chahal', 'role':'bowl', 'wkts':2, 'overs':10, 'runs':45, 'field':0} 
p5={'name':'Kuldeep Yadav', 'role':'bowl', 'wkts':3, 'overs':10, 'runs':34, 'field':0}

t1=run.bat(112,10,0,119,0)
t2=run.bat(120,11,2,112,0)
t3=run.bowl(1,10,71,1)
t4=run.bowl(2,10,45,0)
t5=run.bowl(3,10,34,0)

print(''"name: {} , batscore: {} ".format(p1["name"],t1)
  "name: {} , batscore: {}".format(p2["name"],t2)
  "name: {} , batscore: {} ".format(p3["name"],t3)
  "name: {} , batscore: {} ".format(p4["name"],t4)"")
```

Comment: What is the desired output? Are you converting from Python 2.7?

Comment: some syntax error is encountered at the print()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding commas.You can also customize the separator.

```
print(
  "name: {} , batscore: {} ".format(p1["name"],t1),
  "name: {} , batscore: {} ".format(p2["name"],t2),
  "name: {} , batscore: {} ".format(p3["name"],t3),
  "name: {} , batscore: {} ".format(p4["name"],t4),
  sep='\n',
)
```